Sriov VF Link Aggregation is not Working Properly with Bond Mode 802.3ad
Below is the Configuration I am trying to create.
Host and Switch Config

On host side config which is SRIOV NIC base device.
Host has two physical port and for each there are 4 vfs created.
On switch (arista/cisco base switch) side these two port are part of the port-channel with vlans configured as trunk over the ports as well on the channel. (mode is LACP)
On side these physical port are also in the lag mode LACP.

Additionally These vf are binded to iavf driver.
I am trying creating a Kubernetes Pod with a dummy container, which will mount the vf from the host through sriov net-attach-defs (with vlans) and using bond-cni these vfs are then aggregated to a bond interface in mode 802.3ad.
bond mode 802.3ad 
miimon 100 
ad_select stable 
xmit_hash_policy layer2 
lacp_rate fast

Once pod is provisioned, I see bond is not able to aggregate the vf interface properly and treating them as a part of two separate lags in LACP.
Please let know if i am missing anything or if you need more info i can provide it.
